# Abstract and interfaces together

Tags: vb.net

I am struggling to understand both abstract and interface approach. Since i get the idea what is the purpose to use one over another is clear. I was trying to found whatever example of using them **both** in action however all tutorials are how to use interface over abstract or vice versa showing usage either for one or another. I would really love to see practical example which could show **both** in action best on some real life example. Additional comments why in specific case you used one over another appreciated. Generics are very welcome to see as well in such example.

I'll propose foloowing example. We got some engine to get files from diffrent locations which could be taken using diffrent protocols as follows. I would like to understand on this example how this could be accomplished with both interfaces and abstract.

```
'As all of protocol has to close and open would it be good to put in abstract?
abstract class Collector

    Protected Id
    Protected Name

    MustInherit Sub OpenConnection
    MustInherit Sub CloseConection

    End Class


    '?
    class Ftp : Collector

    class Sftp: Collector

    class Soap: Collector


    'Interface?
    Public Interface IRepository(Of T, Tkey)
    Function GetAllFiles() As IEnumerable(Of T)
    Function GetAllById(Tkey) as IEnumerable(Of T)
    End Interface
```

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,f956b0c07e86df64

Comment: @HansPassant When it is good abstract class to inherit interface. Is it good when all childs would need that interface?

Answer (score 2):

Some key distinctions:

- An abstract class can contain some *implementation*.  An interface cannot.
- In .NET, a class *can not* inherit from multiple base classes.
- A class *can* implement multiple interfaces

The choice of which approach is really up to you.  In general, it's a choice between the Composition pattern or Inheritance.

Composition uses Interfaces.  Think of an object as *having* X.

Inheritance uses Classes.  Think of an object as *being* X.

In either case, an abstract class or an interface is just a Type, through which you will access and manipulate them.  For example, if you have some code that wants to perform `Insert`/`Update`/`Delete` operations, it doesn't need to know that the object it is operating on *is* a FTP client--only that the object *has* the ability to support these operations.  (and that is exactly what `IRepository` specifies)

You definitely can combine both. There's no reason a concrete `FtpClient` class couldn't inherit from an abstract `Protocol` class and also implement the `IRepository` interface. It could even use generics!

Interfaces are great for decoupling your code, and also great for unit test mocks.

There is also a good summary of pros & cons on [Wikipedia (Composition_over_inheritance)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).  Pros:

> To favor composition over inheritance is a design principle that gives the design higher flexibility. It is more natural to build business-domain classes out of various components than trying to find commonality between them and creating a family tree. For example, a gas pedal and a wheel share very few common traits, yet are both vital components in a car. What they can do and how they can be used to benefit the car is easily defined. Composition also provides a more stable business domain in the long term as it is less prone to the quirks of the family members. In other words, it is better to compose what an object can do (HAS-A) than extend what it is (IS-A).
>
> Initial design is simplified by identifying system object behaviors in separate interfaces instead of creating a hierarchical relationship to distribute behaviors among business-domain classes via inheritance. This approach more easily accommodates future requirements changes that would otherwise require a complete restructuring of business-domain classes in the inheritance model. Additionally, it avoids problems often associated with relatively minor changes to an inheritance-based model that includes several generations of classes.

Cons:

> One common drawback of using composition instead of inheritance is that methods being provided by individual components may have to be implemented in the derived type, even if they are only forwarding methods. In contrast, inheritance does not require all of the base class's methods to be re-implemented within the derived class. Rather, the derived class only needs to implement (override) the methods having different behavior than the base class methods. This can require significantly less programming effort if the base class contains many methods providing default behavior and only a few of them need to be overridden within the derived class.

Comment: that's mostly what i know so far reading lot of articles. However what my point is to see concrete example combining both (not picking up concrete either abstract or interfaces). So far everywhere i see either "dry text" explaining one over another or example based on one of them. Haven;t seen both in action o real example. I know it's open point either to use this or another, however would like experts to share proposition what could be used in abstract class and what can be done using interfaces.

Comment: According to my example. I am bit confused as all the methods i shown could be consumed either in interface/s exposing methods like Open/Close/GetFiles, even (Of T where class, new()... to make it more generic. However those methods could be also used in abstract class with the addition that i could make initial shared functionality code for each of them.

Comment: @JaredDykstra ok maybe the question could be then when it is good abstract class to inherit interface. Is it good when all childs would need that interface?

Comment: It's useful to use an abstract base class when you want to consolidate some implementation.  However, the base class only needs to be abstract if there is at least one pure virtual function.  Otherwise, use a regular (non-abstract) base class

Comment: @JimmyJimm - using an abstract base class *forces* all children to provide an implementation for any pure virtual members.

Comment: @JimmyJimm - There is hardly any practical difference.  The main distinction is that if you use interfaces, you can have more than one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you want to have an example combining both. Let's just say both are valid ways to build solid software architecture. They're just two tools - like having a kitchen knife and a meat cleaver. You won't necessarily use them together but see the pro's and con's when looking at the dinner you want to serve.

So usually you take abstract/MustInherit classes if you want to provide a common denominator. Sub-classes derive from the abstract one and have to implement the methods just like they would if they implemeted an interface. The good thing here is that abstract classes can provide "base logic" which can be developed centrally and all the sub-classes can make use of that. In the best case, abstract classes provide kind of "hooks" to plug in special logic in the sub-classes.

Interfaces describe what a class has to fulfill. So everything an interface defines has to be implemented in classes implementing the interface. There's no reusable logic built-in in this approach like in abstract base classes but the big "pro" for interfaces is that they don't take away the single base type you can derive from like abstract classes do. So you can derive from anything or nothing and still implement an interface. AND: You can implement multiple interfaces.

One word to the "reusable logic" with interfaces. While this is not really wroing, the .NET framework allows use to write [extension methods](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2016/07/05/what-is-the-extension-method-in-c.aspx) on types (and interfaces) to attach externally developed code. This allows code reuse with interfaces like having a method implemented in there. So for example, you could write an extension method `None()` for the interface `IEnumerable` which is checking whether the enumerable is empty.

```
public static bool None(this IEnumerable values)
{
    return !values.Any();
}
```

With this, `None()` can be used on any `IEnumerable` in your code base having access to the extension method (in fact, `Any()`, `Select()`, `Where()`, etc. are extension methods as well, lying in the `System.Linq` namespace).

Comment: really appreciate your contribution. However i still see what let's say "i know from theory". I believe in enterprise applications there are a lot of combining both. The main point in this topic is to provide an example showing both in action (it's not a must to be based on example i provided). I believe that is really possible to show by someone.

Comment: Well, you see a lot of interface usage when using Dependency Injection and for that yes, it can be the case that you have an abstract base class - just because it makes sense to put base logic in there - with dependencies  defined through interfaces as constructor arguments. So maybe you have all different kind of repositories for data access like `UserSqlRepository` and `DepartmentSqlRepository`, an abstract base class `SqlRepository` with dependecies to a `ISqlConnectionProvider`. That's something I can think of but I don't know if that is what you are searching for.